# How to find Google Plus Page related to Google Place ID via Web JS SDK

Tags: google-maps, google-plus, google-places-api

I use google place search in my app, and show place details to user ([getDetails](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlacesService) method), but it has mostly data about place location.

So I need to find google plus page of place to get more info about it.

---

### Edit

Sorry if I wasn't clear. 
I know how to get data via `Google Place API` and `Google Plus API`, what I want to know - how to get data from `Google Plus API` about `place` that I found via `Google Place API`

Answer (score 1):

You have to grab the name and address (at least city and state) from google+ and then do a textsearch using google place API.
Yes you might get many results, then you have to filter it. Usually I'm comparing using exact name.

NOTE: You need to connect a google+ to google maps in order for your page to be listed on google place api search. Here's how:
https://support.google.com/business/answer/6010825?hl=en

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the Google Places API to get the details of the place. You first need to get the Place_ID of a place and need to have an API_KEY in order to get various details of the place. These details includes Lat/Lng, Name, Phone Number, Reviews, Rating, Type etc. The REST API to get this is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can get the response either in JSON or XML.

For additional details, take a look at this official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't answer my question, made changes to question